# That is my program in C++ using OpenCv library to read the sequence of images from a dataset, but it doesn't run

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
VideoCapture cap("F:/TestIJCNN2013Download/%05d.ppm");
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
cap.read(frame);
imshow("frame" , frame);
return 0;
}
```

The program compiled with zero errors but doesn't run. How can I run the program correctly, is that false logic or something else.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. E.g. you can start with simple print statements to see where the program crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [`cv::waitKey()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey) call. The image will not be displayed unless you use this function.

Please refer this short code on using [`VideoCapture()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#VideoCapture) for more details.

Comment: it worked...thanks

Comment: np. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted/useful etc